# Create a BindableProperty depending on multiple properties

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, data-binding, properties, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to bind a UI element to different model properties `A`, `B` and `AB`. The first two properties `A` and `B` are controlled by two sliders. The third property `AB` is the sum of `A` and `B`. For each of the three properties there is a label displaying its value.

Now if I move one of the sliders, the corresponding label updates its `Text`. But the label for the combined property `AB` is not updated. Probably no "property changed" event is fired, since there is no setter for `AB`.

**Is there any possibility for binding to such an "aggregated" property?**

Here is the bindable object containing the properties `A`, `B` and `AB`:

```cs
public class Settings: BindableObject
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty AProperty = BindableProperty.Create<Settings, double>(p => p.A, 0);
    public static readonly BindableProperty BProperty = BindableProperty.Create<Settings, double>(p => p.B, 0);
    public static readonly BindableProperty ABProperty = BindableProperty.Create<Settings, double>(p => p.AB, 0);

    public double A {
        get{ return (double)GetValue(AProperty); }
        set{ SetValue(AProperty, (double)value); }
    }

    public double B {
        get{ return (double)GetValue(BProperty); }
        set{ SetValue(BProperty, (double)value); }
    }

    public double AB {
        get{ return A + B; }
    }
}
```

And here is the page containing both sliders and the three labels:

```cs
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        var settings = new Settings();

        var sliderA = new Slider();
        sliderA.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => settings.A = e.NewValue;

        var sliderB = new Slider();
        sliderB.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => settings.B = e.NewValue;

        var labelA = new Label{ BindingContext = settings };
        labelA.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "A");

        var labelB = new Label{ BindingContext = settings };
        labelB.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "B");

        var labelAB = new Label{ BindingContext = settings };
        labelAB.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "AB");

        MainPage = new ContentPage {
            Content = new StackLayout {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = { sliderA, sliderB, labelA, labelB, labelAB },
            },
        };
    }
}
```

This is what the running application looks like on iOS:

[image]

**The last label should display the sum of the first two numbers.**

---

**Edit:**

I wonder why I can't write

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty ABProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<Settings, double>(p => p.A + p.B, 0);
```

But this yields the run-time error "System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for AggregatedBindablePropertyMnml.Settings ---> System.Exception: getter must be a MemberExpression"

Comment: Have you tried a multibinding with a custom IMultiValueConverter?

Comment: @Will: I tried using an `IValueConverter`. (As far as I know there is no `IMultiValueConverter` in Xamarin.) But the problem remains: Although the converter is called initially, the label isn't updated.

Comment: IMultiValueConverter and MultiBinding are in the WPF stack, not sure what is included in xamarin.  Anyhow, that's how it is normally done.  You might have to just roll your own solution :/

Comment: Just quickly looking over it, you should get the update if you set the ABProperty in both the AProperty and BProperty setters.

Comment: @Taekahn: Oh yes, that's it! Every property A and B, which AB depends on, needs to take care of updating AB in its setter. So it's quite handy to implement an `UpdateAB()` method and calling it in both setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion from Taekahn (updating AB within the setters of A and B) I came up with the following solution.

By overriding the `OnPropertyChanged` method and setting the `ABProperty`, the bound label text is updated as well. In contrast to modifying each setter individually, this way we only need to modify the `Settings` class at one place.

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
{
    base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    SetValue(ABProperty, A + B);
}
```

Now both sliders impact the third label:

[image]